# Print Timestamp of Stop and Start Services into .txt file

Tags: powershell

I want timestamp when services is stopped/restarted then output to file. The file will become as attached and send to support.

I cannot output to file as my below query seems got error.

```
$hostname = $env:computername
$smtpServer = 'smtpServer' 
$from = "from" 
$recipients = 'recipients'
$Subject = "Services Restarted Successfully on $hostname $ipv4" 
$body = "This mail confirms that the service on $hostname $ipv4 is now running." 
$ipv4 = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
$natip = Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me
$timestamp = (Get-Date)
$output = D:\Testing\Restart.txt
$attachment = $output
$service = 'Apache'
```

Stop service

```
Stop-Service -name $service -Verbose 

do { 
    Start-sleep -s 5 | Write-Output "$timestamp Services is stopped" | Out-file $output
    }  
        until ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Stopped')
```

Start service

```
    start-Service -name $service -Verbose 
do { 
    Start-sleep -s 5 | Write-Output "$timestamp Services is restarted" | Out-file $output
    }  
        until ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Running')
```

Send confirmation that service has restarted successfully

```
Start-Sleep -s 5 

Send-MailMessage -To $recipients -Subject $Subject -Body $body ((gsv Apache) | out-string) -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $attachment
```

Comment: Piping `Start-Sleep` into `Write-Output` doesn't do anything. They should be on separate lines.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Start-sleep -s 5 
        (next line) >> Write-Output "$timestamp Services is stopped" | Out-file $output

are you mean they should be something like this?

Comment: `Start-Sleep -s 5` should be on its own line. Then `Write-Output....| Out-File ...` should be on the next line.

Comment: @AdminOfThings your next line does help me got the output. but i want every output of "$timestamp Services is stopped" show in the .txt too. Seems like the output file will be replace. any idea how to make sure the text is written inside not overwrite the whole .txt file.

Comment: Out-file $output -Append ?

Comment: @DickyMoore if i want my email message body  "text + current service status" . any idea how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in above comments, change your code to

```
Stop-Service -name $service -Verbose
do { 
      Start-sleep -s 5 
      Write-Output "$timestamp Services is stopped" | Out-file $output 
  } until ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Stopped')
```

Actually your `Start-Sleep` cmledt calls output is sent to the pipeline ( `Start-sleep - s 5 |...`). My guess is that `Start-sleep` doesn't returns anything, so nothing is send to the pipeline. Based on that `Write-Output` is not called.

Antoher guess: Assignment to `$output`  fails since your path is not a string, Powershell may interpret the assignment in command mode. Change it to:

```
  $output = "D:\Testing\Restart.txt"
```

Comment: if i want my email message body  "text + current service status" . any idea how should i do it?

Comment: -Body "$($body)+$((gsv Apache).Status)"

Comment: @DickyMoore your trick not work for me. but im using $body = $line1+$line2 method. assigned $line1 = xx, $line2 = xxx. thanks btw :)